# how to make the viewcontroller rotate when added through appdelegate window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have added a viewcontroller in the window of appdelegate class like this:

```
-(void)showSearchView:(BOOL)view
{
    if(view)
    {
        searchViewController = [[SearchView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchView" bundle:nil];
        CGRect viewFrame=searchViewController.view.frame;
        viewFrame.origin.y=-1024;
        viewFrame.origin.x=248;
        [window addSubview:searchViewController.view];
        searchViewController.view.frame = viewFrame;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"UIBase Hidden" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; 
        searchViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,1024);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    else 
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"UIBase Shown" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        searchViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self performSelector:@selector(doTHis) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

    }

}
```

This gets called from other classes through this command
    [apd showSearchView:YES];
where apd is object of appdelegate class

Everything is working fine till here but when i try to rotate it does not rotate. I have even returnd YES in the following method and still it does not rotate:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{   
    return YES;
}
```

What should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remember that UIWindow does not rotate. Perhaps You should add a base view controller and do your rotation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I add a base view controller in that?

Comment: What i meant is add a viewController in window. And in base view controller add your showsearchview method.

Comment: Hey thanks,
I modified this -(void)showSearchView:(BOOL)view as -(void)showSearchView:(BOOL)view fromView:(UIView*)mainView

and then changed the  [window addSubview:searchViewController.view]; to [mainView addSubview:searchViewController.view];
and now evrything is working perfectly. 

Thanks a ton or I wouldnt have know for long time. :)

Comment: @SahilTyagi Glad to be of some help :)